# NHibernate: Overriding automapping on a one to many relationship

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I've just started to play around with Fluent NHibernate and would like some help / pointers on how I got about mapping this. Here's the domain model I'm working with:

**Class User**: Your standard user class

**Class Preference**: A set of key value pairs. A user can have many preferences.

**Class Post**: Omitted complete description for the sake of brevity, but a user creates a post and it can contain one or more preferences.

So, to recap:

```
class User 
{
    IList<Preference> Preferences;
    IList<Post> Posts;
} 

class Post
{
    IList<Preference> PostData;
}
```

Hibernate automapper comes up with the following DB Structure:

```
User
------------------------
User_Id

Preference
------------------------
Preference_Id | User_Id | Post_Id

Post
------------------------
Post_Id | User_Id
```

The preference table looks ugly to me and would much rather have something like:

```
User
------------------------
User_Id

Preference
------------------------
Preference_Id | User_Id

Post
------------------------
Post_Id | User_Id | Preference_Id
```

Any help on how to do this is much appreciated! I already have a class that implements the IAutoMappingOverride interface, but I'm not sure how to do the actual mapping.

Thanks, 
Teja

Comment: what is Preference_Id in Post table good for? You said a post has many Preferences. Also does `Post.Preferences` contain the same elements as `User.Preferences`?

Comment: Yes .. The Post.Preferences always contains data from User.Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I would reference this configuration to get you manual and auto mappings configured correctly:
[Mixing Mixing Automapping and manual mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530177/fluent-nhibernate-mixing-automapping-and-manual-mapping)

I also noticed you have some composite keys in both your preference and post tables I would look into learning how to map composite keys. Here is a link that might help you with mapping composite keys(primary key with more than one column):
[Using Fluent NHibernate to map Composite Keys](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/01/16/using-fluentnhibernate-to-map-composite-keys-for-a-table.aspx)

As far as your fluent maps go the following might get you pointed in the right direction you can map `one-to-many` relationships using both `HasMany` or `References` depending on which table you want the foreign key on:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap(){
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("User_Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        HasMany(x => x.Preferences);
    }
}
public class PostMap: ClassMap<Post>
{
    public UserMap(){
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Post_Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        References(x => x.Preferences); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since the preferences are the same a simple property is enough

```
class Post
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Preference> Preferences { get { return User.Preferences; } }
}
```